# Java URL library for grabbing lines on a website

Tags: java

I want to be able to grab `N` lines (HTML text content that start on new lines) on a specific `URL` e.g. `www.sitename.com` and store them as `strings` in an array.

something like

```
public void grabLines(){

//create instance of class from imported library

//pass sitename into it

//from the instance, call a method for grabbing the lines on the site and pass in "N" as a parameter

//the  method returns an array/list of N Strings that I can access later

}
```

Is there a native Java library I can import to do this? Does it allow me do what I want easily?

Thanks

Comment: you mean, lines of HTML content? Not parts of the url itself?

Comment: lines of text...sentences that start on distinct lines @Bozho yes I mean lines of HTML content.

Comment: Note that HTML does not have a concept of "lines". How the text is laid out on screen depends on what the size of the screen is, what font is used etc. - in other words, the layout is dynamic. The lines that you see on your screen are not always what anyone else sees.

Comment: sure but a useful Java URL class should have some notion of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to make a screen scraper? you will be pulling html as opposed to just what you see. also if the website is dynamic you won't be able to pull everything that you can see. If you want just html and stuff you can try something like this. I tried to build a bloomberg screen scraper and then parse out the random html tags.

```
 try {
        URL bbg = new URL("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/economic-calendar/");
        BufferedReader r =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( bbg.openStream()));
        while( (temp = r.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: note that this solution does not correctly handle different character sets.  you should be using the charset for the page to convert the bytes into characters.

Comment: @jtahlborn, yes you are right. As you can probably tell, it was pretty lazy coding. I'm curious though. How do you get the charset? Is there a better way then trying to detect the <meta charset=ABCD> tag and switching based on that?

Comment: @jtahlborn can you explain what you mean in a bit more detail?

Comment: the best way to determine the charset is using the Content-Type http header, as the charset is generally included as part of this.

Answer (score 1):

Apache HttpClient is an abstraction above the URL/Reader technique above, but similar: [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)